# Which is grammatically correct? ("then passing" vs "then we pass")

Tags: commas, gerunds

> We find this processes’ PID by running the command “ps ax," **then we pass** this PID to Cycript to allow it to inject itself into the application.

or

> We find this processes’ PID by running the command “ps ax,” **then passing** this PID to Cycript to allow it to inject itself into the application.

Which of the two sentences are grammatically correct, if any?

Comment: unrelated to your question, "**this processes'**" is wrong.  Either there is one _process_ or you're finding the PID of _the processes_ (or perhaps _these processes_).

Comment: the command is "ps ax", not "ps  ax,".

Comment: The first sentence is correct if you mean that we first find the PID, then next we pass the PID. The second sentence is correct if you mean that we find the PID by first running ps ax and then passing the PID. I assume you mean the former, but only you can know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences have multiple grammatical errors. In the first one, it is often considered wrong to use "then" as a coordinating conjunction between two sentence phrases, "We find...we pass...." Most U.S. editors would flag the use of "then" between two sentence phrases and recommend either adding the word "and" before it, or separating the sentence into two, with the second starting, "Then, we pass..." The second sentence is more correct and elegant in its basic construction: "We find...by running...then passing...." (However, at first, it seemed like you might be trying to write: "...then [,] passing... [,]..." leaving a modifying phrase without a phrase object, which would be worse.)

In any case the other errors are still distracting: 1. "this processes'" should be "this process's." 2. The meaning of "it" in "pass this PID to Cycript to allow it to inject itself" is ambiguous, and would be clarified by "the PID." 3. The use of "inject" for an inanimate object (that performs this action on itself) would be frowned upon by my English teachers, who would probably advise me to write, "to allow the PID to *be injected*...".

(Also, sorry to nitpick, but your question itself had a subject-verb error. It should be: "Which of the two sentences **is** [not *are*] grammatically correct?")

Answer (score -1):

"Then we pass" is grammatically correct.